# How do I create a new line with reStructuredText?

Tags: line-breaks, markup, restructuredtext

How do I force a line break/new line in rst? I don't want it to be a new paragraph (ie. no additional spaces between the lines), I just want the text to start on a new line. Thanks!

Answer (score 55):

The [line block syntax](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks) also worked, and was a bit cleaner:

`| This is a line
 | This is another line
 | Another new line`

Comment: And this works with github rst (where raw html and many directives are not available).

Comment: Works in `VS Code` on `Windows 10` without anything else required (just add a `|` to every line beginning of the subsequent lines you would like to have as a contiguous block having newlines without empty lines between them)

Comment: Maybe it's just `pypi.org`, however it did not give me a line break without a new paragraph. To get a new line immediately following a few long lines I have to a) start a new (empty) line and b) THEN (on the next line) follow it with `| <my new line>`. This works ... <my new line> immediately comes after the previous text.

Comment: This should be the accepted solution, as it works for a much wider variety of use cases

Comment: @Aendie: You may put the entire paragraph in a line-block. Long lines may be broken in the source (indent the continuation to match the start) and will automatically be wrapped in the output. See the example Steve Piercy's answer below.

Answer (score 31):

According to the docs for [docutils `raw` role](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#raw), you can do this:

```
If there just *has* to be a line break here,
:raw-html:`<br />`
it can be accomplished with a "raw"-derived role.
But the line block syntax should be considered first.
```

You will need to define the `raw` role first:

```
.. role:: raw-html(raw)
    :format: html
```

As the example states, consider [line block syntax](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks) first.

```
| Lend us a couple of bob till Thursday.
| I'm absolutely skint.
| But I'm expecting a postal order and I can pay you back
  as soon as it comes.
| Love, Ewan.
```

Comment: Thanks. This required defining the raw role first:

`.. role:: raw-html(raw)
   :format: html`

Comment: It might be worth noting that you must indent before each | for it to start a new line.

Comment: @asrjarratt not according to [docutils](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks). One *may*, not *must*, and only if nesting is desired.

Comment: @StevePiercy I stand corrected. I think there was a case where I was having trouble getting it to work without indenting it, and I've just been indenting ever since. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 15):

We added a substitution to our `global.rst` file so we didn't have to add raw tags all the time.

```
.. |br| raw:: html

  <br/>
```

This way we can just use `|br|` when we need a line break.

Comment: To avoid top & bottom padding of a linebreak, replace `<br/>` with `<div style="line-height: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0"></div>`

Comment: This I like. Light and specific. The other general raw HTML role answer is good too, but this minimal markup is nice. When using [restview](https://mg.pov.lt/restview/) I also find that the given answer with`<br/>` works best and does not add top and bottom padding with my CSS. Using the suggested `<div>`, though, leads to separation because the `restview` parser appears to trigger an end of paragraph when encountering the `<div>` tag, leading to exactly the opposite of what's needed.