# Arbitrary line breaks in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Sphinx allows arbitrarily placed line breaks in HTML output with the |br| notation. However this does not work with Latex or EPUB. Is there any way in Sphinx to specify arbitrary line breaks in an output platform independent manner? The problem I face is that I use lists such as

```
* Line 1
  Line 2
```

and this will not allow line blocks on line 2

Comment: Have you tried line blocks? https://stackoverflow.com/a/51216339/407651

Comment: They do not work because the line block must be in column zero which destroys indentation in nested lines within nested lists.

Comment: Can you provide an example of "nested lines within nested lists"?

Comment: What happens if you put `| ` in front of both `Line 1` and `Line 2`?

Comment: @mzjn I get crazy indenting of Line 2. Line2 is either not-indented at alL (happens with a visual indent of 2) or gets an indent of 5 spaces if I use the natural visual indent of 3.I can find no Indenting which will align Line 2 properly with an indent of 3 spaces.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what the problem is (in the question, not in comments). How can we reproduce it? What exactly is the wanted result?

Answer (score 0):

```
* | Line 1
  | Line 2
```

works fine here.

> Indentation in line blocks creates a nested structure, the amount of the indentation is not preserved. The indentation of a nested line block can be customized in a custom stylesheet.
> -- [rST Markup Specification](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#line-blocks)

If you want to keep the input indentation use a literal block:

```
* ::

     Line 1
        Line 2.
```